# How to solve mysql close warning

Tags: mysql

I have tried 
this code-

```
$query=mysql_query("insert into ims(emp_name,emp_id,department,subject,date,matter)
    value('".$_SESSION['name']."','".$_SESSION['eid']."','".$_SESSION['dept']."','".$_POST['subject']."','".$_POST['date01']."','".$_POST['textarea2']."')") or die("Inenatry Error");

<?php  mysql_close($query);?>
```

I got error:

```
 Warning: mysql_close(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in
```

Comment: Compare your code with this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: You're passing the result of your query to `mysql_close()`, though I don't undertsand why. `mysql_close()`, no parameters, would do the job, but there are so many things wrong here I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_close()](https://www.php.net/mysql_close) accepts a connection resource as parameter

Suppose you have your connection like this

```
$connection = mysql_connect(...);
```

then use

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

For more information see [this](https://www.php.net/mysql_close).

**Warning :** mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: Not actually passing a string, but the result set from his query.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like

```
    $db_conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "******");
mysql_close($db_conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Well, you'd have to show us this line. Generally, though, using mysql_close() isn't needed - the connection is automatically closed when the script has finished executing.

<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); 
if (!$link) { 
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. mysql_close will take mysql connection resource not query object. So your code should like that.

```
$conn = mysql_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS');
mysql_select_db('DB_NAME');

$query = mysql_query("insert into ims(emp_name,emp_id,department,subject,date,matter) value('".$_SESSION['name']."','".$_SESSION['eid']."','".$_SESSION['dept']."','".$_POST['subject']."','".$_POST['date01']."','".$_POST['textarea2']."')") or die("Inenatry Error");

mysql_close($conn);
```